# Cannot sum numbers received from stdin using bc

Tags: bash, shell, bc

I'm trying to calculate the average entropy of files contained in a folder using:

```
{ echo '('; find . -type f -exec entropy {} \; | \
  grep -Eo '[0-9.]+$' | \
  sed -r 's/$/+/g'; echo '0)/'; 
  find . -type f | wc -l; }  | \
tr -d '\n' | bc -l
```

`entropy` being an executable which calculates the Shannon entropy of a file, giving outputs of the form:

```
$ entropy foo
foo: 5.13232
```

The aforementioned command errors out with:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

However, the generated output seems to have no problems:

```
$ { echo '('; find . -type f -exec entropy {} \; | \
    grep -Eo '[0-9.]+$' | \
    sed -r 's/$/+/g'; echo '0)/'; \
    find . -type f | wc -l; }  | \
  tr -d '\n'
(5.13232+2.479+1.4311+0)/3
```

And this works too:

```
$ echo '(2.1+2.1)/2' | bc -l
2.1
```

What is wrong with the mentioned command?

Comment: Are you willing to use `awk`? Would be substantially easier.

Comment: You're just missing a trailing endline for the `bc` command: compare `printf '(5.13232+2.479+1.4311+0)/3' | bc -l` with `echo '(5.13232+2.479+1.4311+0)/3' | bc -l`. (your `tr -d '\n'` command removes the trailing newline that `bc` needs).

Comment: An easy fix is to insert `{ cat; echo; }` between the `tr` and the `bc`: `tr -d '\n' | { cat; echo; } | bc -l` or to replace the `tr -d '\n'` part with: `{ tr -d '\n'; echo; }`

Comment: Use `paste -sd'\0' -` instead of `tr -d '\n'` to preserve the last newline character. (see also `paste -sd+ -` to join lines with `+`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> And this works too: `echo '(2.1+2.1)/2' | bc -l`

Ah, but did you try:

```
echo '(2.1+2.1)/2' | tr -d '\n' | bc -l
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Using `echo -n` will accomplish the same thing -- there's no terminating newline, and that's your problem.

Answer (score 4):

`bc` has some pretty particular syntax. `dc` is less choosy:

```
find . -type f -exec entropy \{\} + |
sed 's/.*://;N;N;s/\n[^:]*:/+/g;s/+//;s|$| 3/p|' |
dc
```

I *think* that does what you're trying to do, but I'm not totally certain. An output sample larger than a single line would help.

Comment: You could use `dc` to do all the work too: `{ find . -type f -exec entropy \{\} |
sed 's/.*://' ; echo ' 10k[+]sa[z2!>az2!>b]sbzsclbxlc/p'; } | dc`. The ugly `10k[+]sa[z2!>az2!>b]sbzsclbxlc/p` is a bunch of junk that tells `dc` to compute the average of the numbers left on the stack (with a scale of `10`) `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - that's better than me, man. Make it an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: No, yours is great! I can't really advocate this `dc` junk anyways—it's only good to be left in this comment area.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - it's pretty crazy fast, though. I wanna learn how to use it better. Thanks for the study material...